# ASPX command line

Tags: c#, asp.net, command-line

We have this on the command line

> http://webapps.seattleu.edu/SUOnlineMailer/mailer.login?ReturnUrl=%2fSUOnlineMailer%2fDefault.aspx

It is missing an argument. The code behind is looking for, in addition to an assignment to `ReturnURL`, an assignment to `To`. What would that look like?

Comment: I think you mean `we have this url string`. Are you actually using the command line for this, or just web addresses?

Comment: Is your question "how to escape `&` in Windows CMD/BAT files/command line"?

Answer (score 1):

The way query strings work is like this:

```
file.html?firstArg=firstValue&secondArg=secondValue&...
```

So if you want to add `To`, it would be

> http://webapps.seattleu.edu/SUOnlineMailer/mailer.login?ReturnUrl=%2fSUOnlineMailer%2fDefault.aspx&To=somevalue

Just remember to url escape any values that need to be.

If you (and your question is quite unclear) are asking about escaping characters for command line use, then go read [the documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true). In short: put a `^` before `&`, `|`, `(`, and `)` characters.